# PFGrid Databinding

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, controls

Does anyone have experience with PFGrid? There are just a handful of mentions on stackoverflow, none of which address binding. The company website's forum link is broken.

The DataSource property in the Winforms designer shows one entry: (none)

I am able to assign a datasource in code, but would like to determine what its design-time capabilities are, and whether or not the thing is broken. Does anyone have any useful information about this product, especially as regards its use in the designer?

The namespace of the control in the ToolBox is CG.Controls.Grid and the control name is TreeListView.

I've emailed the firm but have not yet received a reply.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A day after emailing the company it bounced. Looks like the maker of this product has drug up.

---

:
194.25.134.9 does not like recipient.
Remote host said: 550-5.1.1 user unknown
550 5.1.1 Unknown recipient.
Giving up on 194.25.134.9.